# How to change AJAX ColorPickerExtender from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have this code:

```
                   <div class="entryrow">
                    <div class="input" style="width: 40%;">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtColor" runat="server" Width="95%" Font-Size="Large"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <div class="input">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnColorPicker" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/icons/colorpicker.png" />&nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <ajaxToolkit:ColorPickerExtender runat="server" ID="cpBackgroundColor" TargetControlID="txtColor" OnClientColorSelectionChanged="colorChanged"
                        SampleControlID="imgbtnColorPicker" PopupButtonID="imgbtnColorPicker" />
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>

               <asp:HiddenField ID="hfColor" runat="server" />
```

and js:

```
    function colorChanged(sender) {
        sender.get_element().style.color =
             "#" + sender.get_selectedColor();
    };
```

How can I set the ColorPickerExtender color from the code behind when I load the page. From the code I take the current color for this element and put it in the Hidden field. How do I trigger an event about changing color in ColorPickerExtender?

Comment: Were you able to do this?

Comment: Up! Did this get resolved?